# How can I find the average of the ordinate of an indefinite number of lists of points?

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose that I have three lists:

```
list1 = {{0, 1}, {0.1, 10}, {0.2, 100}};
list2 = {{0, 1}, {0.1, 10}, {0.2, 100}};
list3 = {{0, 2}, {0.1, 20}, {0.2, 200}};
```

In each list, the abscissas represent time (my system was measured at the times 0, 0.1, and 0.2 seconds, for example), whereas the ordinates are the measured values.

I would like to create a function `f` that finds the average (i.e., the mean) of the ordinates.  So:

```
f[list1, list2, list3]
```

should give the output:

> {{0, 4/3}, {0.1, 40/3}, {0.2, 400/3}}

I would like `f` to be able to take two or more lists as input.  All lists are given to have the same number of points.

I think that one way to write `f` is:

```
f[lists__] := Transpose[{First[{lists}][[All, 1]], 
  Map[Mean, Transpose[Map[#[[All, 2]] &, {lists}]]]}]
```

Can you please help me think of a cleaner, more succinct, and possibly faster way to do this?

Comment: `f[a_, b_, c_] := Mean[{a, b, c}]`. So `f[list1, list2, list3]` returns `{{0, 4/3}, {0.1, 40/3}, {0.2, 400/3}}`. Is this what you wanted ?

Comment: @Artes Yes, except that I would like `f` to take an arbitrary number of lists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just do:

```
f[list__] := Plus[list]/Length@{list}
```

or simpler, using the built-in `Mean`:

```
f[list__] := Mean[{list}]
```

Using this with your example:

```
f[list1, list2, list3]
(* {{0, 4/3}, {0.1, 40/3}, {0.2, 400/3}} *)
```

Comment: (+1) ... or `f=Mean[{##}]&`.

Comment: ...or `Composition[Mean, List][list1, list2, list3]`.